# Single-Shot/Fire-and-Forget Animator for animating basic state changes (animate*AsState's single-shot equivalent))

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to animate only once and I'm trying different options. I wanted to use animate*AsState but that doesn't work since you have to kind of trigger it by doing some kind of SideEffect with LaunchedEffect when entering in that screen like this:

```
@Composable
fun StartAnimation(width: Float = 0f) {
    var startAnimation by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val widthAnimation = animateDpAsState(targetValue = if(startAnimation) width.dp else 0.dp, tween(600))
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 30.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(20.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.Black)
                .width(widthAnimation.value)
                .height(20.dp)
                .background(Color.Black)
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        startAnimation = true
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this and I'm missing it?

Comment: Are you swapping between screens by using `AnimatedContent`? Because the [`animateEnterExit` modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/AnimatedVisibilityScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).animateEnterExit(androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition,androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition,kotlin.String)) would apply then and let you kick off an animation only when to go to that screen.

Comment: Not my case, I was looking for animating only when entering the screen but good to know @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything that will let you get rid of LaunchedEffect. But this might be better, at least you don't have to use that artificial variable:

```
val animatableWidth = remember { Animatable(0.dp, Dp.VectorConverter) }
LaunchedEffect(width) {
    animatableWidth.animateTo(width.dp, tween(600))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a custom fire-and-forget system. Works as a single-shot animator and can be spawned practically as many times as you like, in parallel.

```
@Composable
fun animateFloatAsState(
    initialValue: Float,
    targetValue: Float,
    delay: Long = 0,
    animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> = spring<Float>(),
    visibilityThreshold: Float = 0.01f,
    finishedListener: ((Float) -> Unit)? = null
): State<Float> {
    var trigger by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    return animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (trigger) targetValue else initialValue,
        animationSpec = animationSpec,
        visibilityThreshold = visibilityThreshold,
        finishedListener = finishedListener
    ).also {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            delay(delay)
            trigger = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is for `Float`, but can as easily be translated to fit `Dp`. I think it is just replacing the word `Float` with `Dp`

Comment: You can even remove the `delay` if that's not something you wish for, and maybe that will entirely eliminate the `LaunchedEffect`, but you'll still need to use the `also` block. I'm not sure about this, but do definitely try it out.

Comment: I've removed the delay, this is for me the best solution to my case, and likely will be using it in other projects :)

Comment: Just a follow up note: you should not have removed the delay. It was defaulted to 0 anyway so it was never necessary to provide it at the calling site, but you've always have had the option to add one if you required at the time. Also, did it work without the side-effect when you removed the delay?

Comment: I realized that you probably don't need to use the also block when you're not adding delays. Just setting the trigger to true after your call to animate*AsState should suffice.

Comment: Yeah it worked without delay and yes you could even remove the `.also{}` (I think)

Comment: I knew it works without delay i was just suggesting that you still keep it, so that you have maximum functionality available.